# Apache Commons : List Handling in CompositeConfiguration

Tags: apache-commons, apache-commons-config

I have two configuration files :

```
override.xml looks like this ...
<paths>
 <path>1</path>
 <path>2</path>
 <path>3</path>
</paths> 
<numbers>
 <number>100</number>
 <number>200</number>
</numbers>

default.xml looks like this ...
<paths>
 <path>4</path>
 <path>5</path>
 <path>6</path>
</paths>
<alphabets>
 <alphabet>A</alphabet>
 <alphabet>B</alphabet>
</alphabets>
```

I'm using a CompositeConfiguration. Adding override.xml first and then default.xml.

```
When I do a getList("paths.path") on the CompositeConfiguration, I get back 1,2,3,4,5,6.
```

This tells me I'm getting back values from both override.xml and default.xml.
Is there any way to get back values only from override.xml only since it overrides the default.xml values ?

At the same time if I were to do a getList("numbers.number"), I would expect 100,200 to be returned. A getList("alphabets.alphabet") to return A,B.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the contents of the list is the default behavior of getList of CompositeConfiguration. What you need to use is a CombinedConfiguration with appropriate NodeCombiner. For your use case, OverrideCombiner is appropriate.
Sample code :

```
XMLConfiguration x1 = new XMLConfiguration();
....
XMLConfiguration x2 = new XMLConfiguration();
....
CombinedConfiguration config = new CombinedConfiguration(new OverrideCombiner());
config.addConfiguration(x1);
config.addConfiguration(x2);
```

Here the list defined in configuration x1 is returned when you do a config.getList("numbers.number")